# Is it possible to deploy customization from sandbox to production without running Apex code test ?

Tags: apex, deployment, custom-field, sandbox

I have some customization in the sandbox and that customization don't have any Apex code in it.
Is it possible to deploy that customization without running Apex run test? 
The problem is that when i deploy it apex code test fails with error

> Your organization's code coverage is 69%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment

Can anybody help me out ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "some customization in the sandbox and that customization don't have any Apex code in it." can you please ellaborate this?

Comment: @RajivBhatt i have customized few fields without using any apex code in it. Is it necessary to Run all test . Is there any way to disable the apex test because i am not deploying any apex code for this change

Answer (score 2):

This is documented by Salesforce. Seems like you dont have any option but to  increase the code coverage by creating new or updating your existing test classes.

> If the deployment includes components for any of the following
>   metadata types, all the tests are automatically run.

- ApexClass
- ApexComponent
- Custom Field
  etc.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm

Answer (score 1):

No, when you deploy all tests in your production org will run.  It is likely you had much higher code coverage one point in time.  New validation rules or required fields may cause apex tests to fail.  To increase your code coverage, run all tests and see which ones are failing.  Then update those tests and deploy to production.

Comment: i am not deploying any apex code right now i am just deploying some customization that contains no apex code. Is it necessary to run apex run test for this also ?

Comment: Yes, all deployments will cause apex tests to run.

Comment: @SFDCNOOB This answer isn't *quite* right. It is possible to deploy without tests running, but it depends on *what* you're deploying.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, I should have been more specific in my answer and referenced documentation as Rajiv Bhatt did above.

Comment: @sfdcfox As i said earlier i am deploying a simple custom object right now and later on will deploy some more object like this. Can you tell me how it is possible.